# Edit in Place CMS Suggestions

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, editing, content-management

I need to find a [very] easy to use (for editors/authors) CMS. Preferably with edit-in-place editing similar to [SiteCore](http://www.sitecore.net/).

We don't need something as huge and powerful as SiteCore though. Users need the ability to add pages (using set templates that we in development have provided), they also need the ability to add and editing content, with it being approved before publishing.

Ideally we're looking for a .Net solution as our other web projects are .Net MVC - but PHP options are still ok.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked at it for a while, but I thought [Concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/) had a lot of potential with its in-context editor.

Comment: This looks great, if only it was .NET (for my purposes)

Comment: In the end I went for this - having convinced the powers that be that there was no viable .Net option. Thanks!

Comment: well there actually is but I cannot mention it here without violating stack overflow terms.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some experience with [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) CMS. It has the basic functionality of a CMS and it is built on .net. For someone used to a CMS like Sitecore it is quite easy to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Walrus CMS](http://walrus.lt), it's really lightweight and easy to use, but it's build in Java though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help or not, but Mut8 seems like a possible solution to your problem. It seems to allow users to edit pages and stuff like that.

http://mut8.me/