# What ASP.NET MVC 3 CMS Provides Multi-language support?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, globalization, multilingual

What Content Management Systems are built in ASP.NET MVC, are preferably open-source, and provide multi-language support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question around CMS choice some time ago: [Edit in Place CMS Suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867648/edit-in-place-cms-suggestions)

Having tried several I would say that Umbraco CMS is the way to go - Umbraco 5 (currently in pre-production) is written on MVC 3

Answer (score 0):

I think orchard would be a perfect fit: http://www.orchardproject.net/

The gallery is pretty booming : http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery

Its relatively new, but that also makes quite a few things easy to learn. Somethings in orchard, like setup, editing are really simple.

Extending orchard is also brilliant, you don't have to know too much, and themeing is also quite well done.

As for localization see this : http://www.orchardproject.net/localize

Orchard is fully localizable and people are contributing!